# How can get best performance on SVG animation (FPS drop on mouseOver)

Tags: javascript, performance, animation, svg, transform

i made my animation frames using SVG and transform inside `requestAnimationFrame()` function:

```
moveSVG: () => {
            if (Melo.onAir) {
                const N = 4 * 60 / Melo.tempo;
                const beatLen = 1 / 16 * N;
                const c16 = 16 * Melo.measures;
                let diff = Melo.nextBeat + (Melo.audioContext.currentTime - Melo.nextWhen) / beatLen;
                while (diff < 0) {
                    diff = diff + c16;
                }
                if (diff > Melo.songLength - 1) {
                    diff = Melo.songLength - 1
                }
                const tapSize = Melo.tapSize
                const y = diff * tapSize;
                Melo.yPos = y;
                const yVal = `translate(0 ${-y - tapSize})`;
                Melo.linesGroup.setAttribute("transform", yVal);
                const telorans = tapSize;
                class animated {
                    constructor(element, beat) {
                        this.element = element
                        this.mover();
                        this.remover(beat);
                    }
                    mover() {
                        this.element.forEach(elem => {
                            this.ele = elem.ele;
                            this.len = elem.len;
                            this.beg = elem.beg - tapSize;
                            this.end = elem.end;
                            this.note = elem.pitch;
                            let newPos = (y - this.end) + this.len + tapSize;
                            if (newPos > this.len) newPos = this.len;
                            if (newPos > -tapSize && newPos < tapSize) {
                                this.score(newPos);
                            }
                            this.animation(newPos)
                        })
                    }
                    animation(newPos) {
                        const eleG = this.ele.children.group;
                        eleG.children[1].style.fill = 'red';
                        eleG.setAttribute('style', `transform: translateY(${newPos}px)`);
                    }
                    remover(beat) {
                        if (y > this.element[0].end || !Melo.onAir) {
                            Melo.anime = Melo.anime.filter(item => item !== beat);
                        }
                    }
                }
                Melo.anime.forEach(beat => {
                    let notes = Melo.noteProg[beat];
                    if (notes) {
                        new animated(notes, beat)
                    }
                });
            }
            requestAnimationFrame(Melo.moveSVG)
    }
```

everything works fine with ~60fps  till mouseOver on SVG elements!

i made a gif for showing that :

**FPS drop on mouseOver**
[image]

then i made another test without animation and with my CPU usage :

**CPU usage on mouseOver**
[image]

and i dont have any mouse event on my svg elements !

i think its normal for browser to checking events! idk , but what can i do for get best performance without FPS drop on my animations , is that a way for remove everything from svg elements ? to get better performance ?

or should i use another way to do that ?

**EDIT:**
i made my test on windows 10 and google chrome 84,i need best way to works on all operation system and browser !

Comment: Best performance on what browser, on what operating system, on what version of those two? It's not a straightforward question because there are too many variables here. You'd likely find using CSS/SMIL rather than javascript more performant though.

Comment: on every browser and every operating system.

Comment: OK, go install them all and test them all.

Comment: How can i use CSS/SMIL on JavaScript , cuz i have to move elements on key press event.

Comment: See row 5 in https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/Test/20110816/harness/htmlObjectApproved/animate-elem-63-t.html if that's not suitable then you will need to use javascript for keypress but you could still trigger SMIL/CSS animations with javascript.

Comment: Thanks for ur time and answer , but can u made me a simple example for do that ?